# Run a service in the background forever

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on an Android application in which I have to compare current time , with a time (saved) in a file, though everything is working fine. I have use services and in service i have use THREAD to run the service infinitely, and in addition to this i have also used PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to continue service even the device is sleep but the issue is that instead of acquiring PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK my service runs for 1/2 hours and then again go to sleep. I don't want to acquire FULL_WAKE_LOCK. Is there any one who can guide me what i have to do in order to run this comparison, i.e. my service will run perfectly once the user set the time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot run a service in the background forever. If nothing else, the user will get rid of it, particularly services that drain the battery the way that you are proposing. Why do you think that you need a service, running forever, keeping the battery on forever, "to compare current time , with a time (saved) in a file"? Why not use `AlarmManager`?

Comment: How I can do that? can you provide me some example / tutorial? Secondly, I am using Services because i want that it should run in background, and compare the saved time with the current time continuously irrespective whether the phone is on sleep or not. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it the wrong way. To create permanent service you must
declare it as foreground. No other way about it:

```
myService.startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, my_notification);
```

If your interest with such a service is to periodically perform fast-ending
actions, and if the in between periods are long, you probably want to use
the [alarm API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and improve your app's battery consumption.

Edit:

To set a foreground service you must supply the system with a notification 
object to be displayed at notification bar for *as long as the service is in foreground*

Why is that? Because foreground services cannot be killed, and Android needs to know
that the user is aware of that fact.

Setting as foreground:

```
static final int NOTIF_ID = 100;

// Create the FG service intent 
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class); // set notification activity
showTaskIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
showTaskIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
showTaskIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();

startForeground(NOTIF_ID, notif);
```

And reverting to 'stardard' service mode:

```
stopForeground(true).
```

Both setting to foreground and reverting to background can be called by either the service itself (e.g. its onCreate() method) or by external code (e.g. the activity that initiated the service). No problems here.

Comment: what is myService? is it the class name?? and i have read on developers.android.com that MY_NOTIFICATION_ID should not be equal to 0 is it right?

Comment: Please review my prior (now edited) post for answers.